# Issue with Connecting to WCF Service using Metro - HTTP Works, HTTPS does not

Tags: java, wcf, ssl, java-metro-framework

I am connecting to a WCF web service with a Java client I am constructing.  Someone else has already successfully built WCF clients to connect to this service. The WSDL available via HTTP provides Message Level Security. The WSDL available via HTTPS uses both TLS and Message Level Security. I understand that using TLS on top of Message Level Security is basically dual-encrypting, but that is a key requirement.

Since I can connect to the HTTP service correctly, I believe I have all the trust store and key store issues resolved.

I am connecting to the service using Metro 2.1.1. I have built the client in both Eclipse and Netbeans. I fetch the WSDL from the HTTP site, and using wsimport (with the -extensions flag) I build and execute the clients successfully.

When I fetch the WSDL using the HTTPS site I can again build both clients successfully. But when I execute them - I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP12Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP12Fault.java:225)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:122)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
at $Proxy43.request(Unknown Source)
```

The only difference between the two WSDLs (the one fetched via HTTP and the other via HTTPS) is the reference in the WSDL to HTTPS:// vs. HTTP://.

I do not have easy access to the WCF service logs - normally there is a 3-6 hour delay between when I request a set of logs and when I can view them.

My question is has anyone encountered a similar circumstance - and is there something I am blatantly missing here? Is there something in a NetMon or Wireshark trace I can look for to see that the issue is? I have been struggling with this for days - any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the service configuration try disabling security context on the endpoint you're using:

```
<message establishSecurityContext="False" clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
```

You can read more about security context token (SCT):

- [Security Context Token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms825747.aspx)
- [Message security knobs](http://zamd.net/2008/02/11/message-security-knobs/)
- [Java client for WCF service with wsHttpBinding over SSL](http://www.java.net/node/684630)